# Time elapsed since last data event

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, future

I have a class (shown below) which receives data updates. My aim is to find out if no data updates have been received 5 minutes since the last data update.

This is my code:

```
public class DataListener {

    private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor;
    private ScheduledFuture<Void> future;

    public DataUpdateListener() {
        executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    }

    /**
     * Start listening for data.
     */
    public void start() {
        // do some setup...

        rescheduleTask();
    }

    /**
     * Called whenever a data event is received.
     */
    public void onEvent(final DataEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Received event: " + event);
        rescheduleTask();
    }

    private synchronized void rescheduleTask() {
        // cancel the existing task
        if (future != null) {
            future.cancel(true);
            executor.purge();
        }

        // schedule a new one
        future = executor.schedule(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() {
                System.out.println("No data events received in the last 5 minutes!");
                // do some stuff...
                shutdown();
                return null;
            }
        }, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    void shutdown() {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }    
}
```

The class maintains a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. Whenever a data update is received, it cancels the existing task and schedules a new one.

I'm wondering if this approach is ok or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: I might be a bit off but if I understand correctly, you are trying to implement a shutdown-timer i.e. if now events are received within 5 mins, shutdown the executor?

Comment: not only that... I have to do some other processing if no events have been received within 5 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a priority queue implementation? If I have not misunderstood your problem, something like a `PriorityBlockingQueue` could be useful in this case. In particular you could check the [`poll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method with a desired timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

In your method, you explicitly `cancel`s the scheduled task, and schedules a new one. This is not **rescheduling**.. This is actually **recreating** a schedule. IMO, it would be better for you to store the "soon-to-be" schedule in a list.. or a `queue` or a `stack`. Then retrieve the task when ready.